# Bad performance after re-install windows

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, performance, gaming

Lately my laptop was having trouble playing certain games because the disk would go to 100%, after trying multiple things to fix it without succes I decided to start from scratch and reinstall windows. Now after I reinstalled windows the disk performance is improves (most likely since it doesn't have as mutch files on there) but whenever I start a game after about 5 minutes it starts having frame drops from 120fps to about 5. that is on any game and the laptop slows down with it, also when those frame drops happen all other programs are affected as well. So it seems to me that it isn't the game doing it but rather something on the laptop. The issue consists of low framerate, being unable to play games that used to run before the reinstall of windows, when having anything of sound playing it goes static/robot.

I've tried several things but nothing has helped so far, so I hope anyone on SuperUser could help me with a solution or even pointing me to something that could be the issue.

**Laptop hardware**

> Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3632QM CPU @ 2.20GHz
>
> Video Card 1  Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000
>
> Video Card 2  NVIDIA GeForce GT 630M
>
> Memory    6.0 GB
>
> Operating System  Microsoft Windows 8 (build 9200), 64-bit

**Things that I have tried**

- I updated the drivers the video card
- defragmentated the disk
- lowered settings and closed background applications

I did find this [similair question](https://superuser.com/questions/320051/degraded-game-performance-after-format) and there the solution is to renew the thermal paste, but since I use a laptop I don't really want to open it up.

If I'm missing any information that might help the find the cause of this please feel free to ask me about it. And since this is my first question here I don't quite know if its on topic for the site, if it isn't just leave a comment saying so and I'll delete it.

**Added information**

[PassMark performance test benchmark](http://www.passmark.com/baselines/V8/display.php?id=41127315232)

Comment: You need to diagnose what occurs when that happens. One way would be to use some benchmarks , and at the same time view the processor frequency and termpsl.  Why benches?  because they can be windowed easily work specific tasks (like cpu mostly or gpu mostly) , and you can use other windows to observe temperatures and processor frequency easily.

Comment: any recommendations on how to do that? or would the [performance test](http://www.passmark.com/products/pt.htm) results be of use?

Comment: That would be a start.  Honestly the fact the problem did not go away indicates a hardware problem not a software problem.  So start with the basics.  Do you have both the current Intel and Nvidia drivers installed?  What versions of those drivers are installed?  Is your HDD reporting itself has healthy?  You indicate I/O on the disk, that indicates, Windows is spending a lot of time writting to the disk which shouldn't be the case if you are running an application that does not write to the disk while its running ( like a game ).

Comment: ill try to get that benchmark and add it to the post in a way (dont want to make this post huge with just the benchmark) all drivers are up to date but I don't know the intel version the nvidia is version 350.12

Comment: i got the benchmark [uploaded](http://www.passmark.com/baselines/V8/display.php?id=41127315232) if this isn't what you were looking for as benchmark just tell me i still have the program open with the test results on there

Comment: No, most of the idea here where you have a working but balking system, would be to observe What is occuring, the bench itself (in this case) not important. Discovering if it is overheating (temps) and throttling (frequency can be seen in resmon for one place) .  Ramhound also brings up the HD which came to mind also, checking it with a smart testing.

Comment: Do a stress test with a software (google for stress test pc) and see if any part fails the test or temp go out of normal range. If the cpu goes beyond 60-70 you have to see the  cooling system on your laptop.

Comment: @Psycogeek I don't quite know what I should do next since the passmark did note that the cpu is around 75-85 and the hdd 56 degrees. However i did change a few settings and now I can at least have a video running and play the a game with drops to about 14 fps but less frequent. so that in it self did help me out.

Comment: @maam27 You have to do something with those crazy temperatures. Don't use the computer when it's so hot, damage might happen.

Comment: @LittleHelper that was from a warm day and its getting summer so that did affect it a little. generally its not near that temp.

Comment: @maam27 Take it to a local computer shop/store/service/whatever and ask them to clean it, it will took few business days at max and it's quite cheap.